# How to permanantly disable /var/log/lastlog?

Tags: centos

When I delete files such as `/var/log/lastlog`, `/var/log/utmp` and `/var/log/wtmp` the files will be recreated.

How do I disable the recreation of those files?

Comment: According to my information the generators of lastlog are hardwired in the kernel. Consequently, they can't be disabled.

Comment: @Ketan Where in the kernel? And how about editting the kernel, since it is open source?

Comment: Do this instead: http://superuser.com/questions/410931/how-do-i-permanently-delete-var-log-lastlog

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @Ketan, the *kernel* has nothing to do with it. All those files are manipulated by numerous userspace tools.

Comment: @RickyBeam Thanks! Do you have a ref I can look into.

Answer (score 6):

You can just link them to `/dev/null`. It will not generate errors like write-immutable solution above:

```
cd /var/log
for file in lastlog utmp wtmp ; do
  unlink $file
  ln -s /dev/null $file
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you would want to, but as Ketan said, they're hard wired into many parts of the system.

Instead you can truncate them, make them read-only and immutable.

```
# cat /dev/null > /var/log/lastlog
# cat /dev/null > /var/log/utmp
# cat /dev/null > /var/log/wtmp
# chmod ugo-w /var/log/lastlog /var/log/utmp /var/log/wtmp
# chattr +i /var/log/lastlog /var/log/utmp /var/log/wtmp
```

In order to be modified they'll need to have the immutable flag removed first.

Comment: It gets overwritten when you logout and login again

Comment: The immutable flag will prevent that. Immutability is all powerful.

Comment: And immutable will cause write errors that can make all logins fail -- depending on your setup.  The simpler answer is to symlink them to /dev/null. (there are too many tools that mess with them to try to disable them.)